# Do i write browser size specific css changes in-line or at the end?

Tags: css, dynamic, browser, sass

So i'm writing some code for dynamic browser resizing and i'm curious where is best practise for placing my code - Do i write it in line with the area i am in, or do i write it at the end and refer back ?

they both work, but i don't want to commit to one route to later find out it's messy as hell :)

Example - placing it in line with the relevant area

```css
ul {
    li {
        font - size: 14 px;
        @media screen and(max - width: 1280 px) {
            font - size: 11 px;
        }
    }
}
```

or referring back to it

```css
ul {
    li {
        font - size: 14 px;
    }
}

@media screen and(max - width: 1280 px) {
    ul {
        li {
            font - size: 11 px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for less code line use the second option because you can't add media query on every class of you css, that would be a waste byte :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3C website examples seem to favor placing media queries at the end of the document, which I believe they do possibly for compatibility reasons, as media queries are CSS3 only. Also, this allows faster parsing of the CSS structure for mobile. Forcing the CSS parser to piece together sections of queries will slow down your initial load time.

If you ignore the question of compatibility, I still would favor placing all media queries at the end, almost as if they were different style sheets. They are like separate style sheets in that they assume a base behavior then modify it. Since vanilla CSS does not yet support variables well, placing them at the end also saves you from duplicating device coordinate values. From an organization point of view, the device area also probably represents the top level organization structure as well. Putting them at the end seems to be standard.